# How to go back to the default clang?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, clang, xcode4.5, macports

I have installed `clang_select` and I have used `port select clang mp-clang-3.3` a while ago, but now install builds seem to crash.

Therefore I'd like to go back to using the original `/usr/bin/clang` command. How can I do that?

I have tried `sudo port select clang none` but it did not work.
(If it is relevant, I have XCode 4.5.)

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe it should be moved to apple.stackexchange: http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: They would tell that developer tools should go to stackoverflow.

Comment: As this is using macports really rather than just a dev tools question I expect it would be on topic for both e.g. http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47575/macports-gcc-select-doesnt-contain-gcc-select and many others tagged with [tag:macports]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, make sure you've installed the `Command Line Tools` component of Xcode 4.5 (`Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads -> Components`).  That will ensure there is a `/usr/bin/clang` installed.  Then, either use that absolute path or modify your shell `$PATH` so that `/usr/bin` comes before `/opt/local/bin` or wherever you have the MacPorts `clang` installed or, if you are not planning to use the MacPorts `clang` at all, you can remove it with `port uninstall clang` or whatever specific port you installed.

Comment: It helped, thx I have installed the new CLT (which has not got updated for some reason), finally I did not have to uninstall just to deactivate clang.